# sort core data by ID

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, swift3

i save different values into my core data.
now i would like the fetch all this data an sort it by something like ID, which will use in mysql.

this is my core data database:

[image]

is there an way to sort it by column Z_PK, which seems to be an incremental number?

Comment: "is there an way to sort it by column Z_PK, which seems to be an incremental number?" YES. But it may be interesting to show some code, what you've tried, how is you entity saved (Int, String ?), and have a look a `sortDescriptor` in fetchRequest.

Comment: @Larme: I don't think so (unless you bypass the Core Data API and access the SQLite store directly). The Z_PK column is an implementation detail and not exposed as a Core Data attribute.

Comment: yes thank you. i solve my problem with sorting it by objectID :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sort by column.

```
class func fetchFromCoreData() -> [ReturnType] {

    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = MyCoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let request:NSFetchRequest<EntityName> = self.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "attributeName", ascending: false)]
    let myCoreDataArray = try? context.fetch(request)
    return myCoreDataArray ?? []
}
```

Comment: It would be great if u could show some code, what you've tried, how is you entity saved, etc